# how to remove current upload file in dropzone?

Tags: jquery, dropzone.js

**Notes :** i tired all questions & answer related this topic.

I want to  remove current upload file in dropzone .i set `alert('i remove current file');` i set max size and any one can upload more than siz document then remove on this time .

**My code** [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/mxxa0bk8/12/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To remove a file from dropzone you simple need to call the `removeFile()` method, The easiest way to do this is with closure.

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#mydropzone", {
  url: "/file/post",
  acceptedFiles: accept,
  maxFilesize: 0.5,
  uploadMultiple: false,
  createImageThumbnails: false,
  addRemoveLinks: true,
  maxFiles: 3,
  maxfilesexceeded: function(file) {
    this.removeAllFiles();
    this.addFile(file);
  },
  init: function() {

    var drop = this; // Closure

    this.on('error', function(file, errorMessage) {
      //alert(maxFilesize);
      //this.removeAllFiles();
      if (errorMessage.indexOf('Error 404') !== -1) {
        var errorDisplay = document.querySelectorAll('[data-dz-errormessage]');
        errorDisplay[errorDisplay.length - 1].innerHTML = 'Error 404: The upload page was not found on the server';
      }
      if (errorMessage.indexOf('File is too big') !== -1) {
        alert('i remove current file');

        // i remove current file
        drop.removeFile(file);
      }
    });
  }

});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wallek876/mxxa0bk8/13/)

Comment: hello @wallwek . your code is work fine.but i still one question arise i upload 6 file is bigger then six time alert are there . but i want to single alert only .can you help me .

Comment: @Sumitpatel I don't think its possible because of the way the files are added. Even when you add multiple files at once, the files are processed one by one, and this causes the events to trigger once for every file.